# Ho to deal with Git warning "a host provider override was set but no such provider..."?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I worked in a git repository without issues.
Some day after calling `git pull` I got the following warning

```
$ git pull
warning: a host provider override was set but no such provider 'gitlab' was found. Falling back to auto-detection.
warning: a host provider override was set but no such provider 'gitlab' was found. Falling back to auto-detection.
Already up to date.
```

Where does it come from and how to get rid of it?

Used Git Version

```
$ git --version
git version 2.31.0.windows.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Git matter. The message is coming from GCM.

https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/14ff019ec854dfd8e41bd1e41e58bd8763888e58/src/shared/Core/HostProviderRegistry.cs

See for example lines 109 / 110.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my reported issue by editing Git configuration and removing all existing and non-used `credential` settings

```
git config --global --edit
```

Afterwards I set the global Git setting for credential helper

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```